# Where to find in server whether the request was made to DNS of website or the Server IP on the port

Tags: linux, nginx, dns

I have a website running on a centos 7 server and the nginx is used to serve the website.

My question is how can I identify in my server that whether the Domain Name of my website was hit or was the request made directly to my linux server's Public IP on the nginx port.

Thanks.

Comment: DNS-servers always translates the name to an ip-address before they connect to the webserver. But the webserver can perform a reverse DNS-lookup to get the hostname, on apache at least. This is usually turned off to increase performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default *combined* logfile format does not show the `http_host` header, which is probably what you need. You can define a custom logfile format (in your `http` block), and reference it from either the `http` block or specific `server` blocks. For example:

```
http {
    log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                      '"$http_host" '
                      '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                      '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx-access.log custom;
    ...
}
```

The above is based on the default configuration with `$http_host` added. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) for details.